# Creating an application for Math Practice with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying a develop a Math Practice web application using ASP.NET (not MVC), which allows Users to perform Multiple choice or simply type an answer, click a button and see answer.

The first idea that comes to mind is simply get permission to use a book, grab all the questions and answers using a DB and display the right answer. But how would I display the answer or the show me how the answer was derived.

My confusion is; how does this work?:

1. Do I have to write all the formulas and answer myself?
2. Are there programs for this?

I do not even know where to start.

What I would like to do is have the user select an answer, if the answer is wrong, they can click the ***show me button***.

I am looking to either write this in C#, Visual Basic using JQuery on the front end.

Just need some direction.

Thanks my friends.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too vague for StackOverflow.  Try breaking it down into more specific, answerable questions. The decisions about overall architecture, including rights to a book, is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Sorry but you should ask question about implementation details. I suggest you to read a beginner's ASP.NET book.

Comment: I don't need a beginners book. I wasn't asking how to create an ASP.NET Page, I am asking how do I write an Application for Math specifically. Not 1 + 1 = 2.

Comment: I think you are [looking for a mentor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180715/191410). I don't think you are going to get that here, but good luck with your project!

Comment: I'll just use a Math College Textbook. Get rights from author, place all the question and answer in a DB from the Textbook and let the user select/show correct answer. Simple but cheap and easy method which I wasn't really looking for. Don't think I'll need implementation help but if I do, I'll ask. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was in college I had to do something very similar.

What I did is stored expressions `4 + 5`; `1 * 6` in database and then pushed those expressions to evaluate on run-time because it is pretty easy in C#.

- It takes expression from database `2 + 2`
- It evaluates the expression on run-time producing result `4`
- You get your result and show it to user or do whatever with it

More info on how exactly to do that: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CodeDomCalculator08082005003253AM/CodeDomCalculator.aspx

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood it just sounds the OP just wants to be able to store questions, along with a few answers for each where one is marked as correct. Then the user types or chooses an answer from a radio button group or the like and submits their answer?

Comment: Thanks, this is a start. Yes its what I am looking to do. The answer will already be in the DB. I am thinking about using a TextBook. But was looking for directions in-terms of where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to evaluate a stored expression.  Since you just want the user to enter multiple choice or the answer itself, just set up your database as follows:

```
QuestionAnswers:
ID (uniqueidentifier) (primary)
QuestionText (varchar)
QuestionAnswer (varchar)
ShowMeHowEquation (varchar)
```

Then, display the ShowMeHowEquation via jQuery like so:

```
<a href="#" class="showMeHow">Show Me How</a>
<div class="showMeHowEquation">Database driven contents here...</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.showMeHow')click(function() {
            $(this).next('.showMeHowEquation').slideDown();
        });
    });
</script>
```